# Is there easy way to duplicate a RowLayout in QtQuick?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

In my ui.qml I have:

```
RowLayout {
    id: rowLayout2
    x: 0
    y: 397
    width: 640
    height: 50
    clip: false

    Text {
        id: text4
        width: 105
        height: 32
        text: qsTr("房间类型")
        font.pixelSize: 17
        wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
    }

    ComboBox {
        id: comboBox1
        activeFocusOnPress: false
        model: ListModel {
                id: cbItems
                ListElement { text: "标准间"; color: "Yellow" }
                ListElement { text: "三人间"; color: "Green" }
                ListElement { text: "大床房"; color: "Brown" }
                ListElement { text: "豪华套房"; color: "Blue" }
            }
    }

}
```

And I want to make a button that when clicked on duplicates this `RowLayout` below the original one, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it inside a `Repeater` and increment the `model` count when the button is clicked.

```
Button {
    onClicked: {
        repeater.model += 1;
    }
}
...
Column {
    Repeater {
        model: 1
        // Your rowLayout2 code
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, it works well,  but the compiler say
    'property alias combobox: combobox1'
is invalid now, so how do I access it

Comment: @arslan2012 Assuming that line is outside of the `Repeater`, it won't work because there could be multiple `combobox1`s. You will need to provide a getter method that calls `Repeater::itemAt(index)` and add the alias to `rowLayout2`. Then you can do: `repeater.itemAt(3).combobox`.